# Kubernetes startup probes gives error message `connect: connection refused` initially before api's are up

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, startup-probe

The startup probe's use to wait for api to available and start liveness probe and now before the health check api's are available, it is throwing the following error

`{level: error, msg: Request to probe app failed: Get "http://<IP>/api/health": dial tcp 127.0.0.6:0-><IP>:8080: connect: connection refused, original URL path = /app-health/service/startupz app URL path = /api/health}`

after 20-30 seconds, when api's are available, then the startup probe is working. May be adding `initialDelaySeconds` might fix the issue but it doesn't make sense to me to use it as it defeats the original purpose of using startup probe.

startup configuration:

```
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/health
            port: rest-server
            httpHeaders:
              - name: X-Request-Id
                value: STARTUP-PROBE
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Adding **intialDealySeconds** will help you to fix this issue. As you stated, the purpose of **startupprobe** is to delay marking the container as ready. So you can increase the **periodSeconds** to more like 20. It will give some time for your probe to recheck the state.